# How to prove that $f$ is a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, euclidean-geometry

Let $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0 \text{ or }x\ge0\}$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x$. I want to find $C \subset X$ closed such that $f(C) \subset \mathbb{R}$ isn't closed.

In other words, I'm searching a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that its intersection with $X$ is something "strange" that doesn't give me a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ when projected onto the $x$ axes (we are taking the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and the subspace topology inducted by the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Try $C = \{(x,y) : x > 0, xy \ge 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, $X=\{(x,0):x<0\}\cup\{(x,y):x\geq0\}$.
So, if we take $C=\{(x,0):x<0\}\cup\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ then $C$ is closed because $X-C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but when we apply $f$ (which is the projection map actually, i.e. continuous 1-1 onto), we have $f(C)=(-∞,0)$ which is obviously open in $\mathbb{R}$.